# MATLAB Figure file trouble

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure, figure

The **Capture** button does capture images and saves it on a single folder. Whenever I'll push the **Capture** button It'll just keeps on capturing and saving images. What I want to do is whenever I will push **Capture** button, it will automatically update the **image1.jpg textbox**.

> To make things clear:
>
> every hit to **Capture button**, the **Edit textbox** updates it's
>   name to image1.jpg, 1 hit again to Capture, Textbox updates to
>   image2.jpg etc.... please help me :(

[image]

**The Capture button's code is**

```
vid = videoinput('winvideo', 2);
set(vid, 'ReturnedColorSpace', 'RGB');
img = getsnapshot(vid);
imshow(img);

%this is where the image will be saved
counter  = 1;
baseDir  = 'C:\Users\Sony Vaio\Documents\Task\Appendix\images\';
baseName = 'image';
newName  = [baseDir baseName num2str(counter) '.jpg'];
while exist(newName,'file')
counter = counter + 1;
newName = [baseDir baseName num2str(counter) '.jpg'];
end    
imwrite(img, newName);
```

**The Process Pushbutton's code that appears in Textbox**

```
 name=get(handles.name,'String');
A=imread(strcat('images/',name));
org=A;
axes(handles.axes1);
[h,w,f]=size(A);
%original image is shown
imshow(A);
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the text box's `String` property?  `set(hTextBox,'String',newName);`

Comment: @chappjc sorry forgot to say that the textbox just serves as the display of the Process pushbutton. The textbox has no property.

Comment: To put the file name in the Edit Textbox, you still need to use the `String` property.  Is the problem how to get the file name stripped away from the full file path?  For that, use `fileparts`.

Comment: the image1.jpg is just a String name. I still have to change image1.jpg to image2.jpg manually. the textbox has no property. The Process button just gets what was in the textbox

Comment: The process button gets what was in the text box _via_ the `String` property.  Try doing `set(handles.name,'String','imageX.jpg')` in the capture button code, as in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you posted the whole code for your capture button's push callback, but I don't see you setting your edit box's `String` property anywhere.

```
set(hEditBox,'String',newName);
```

If you are setting fields in `handles`, don't forget to `guidata(hObject,handles)`.

Comment: it's working but the name is the whole path of the image. the whole directory.

Comment: `newName  = [baseDir baseName num2str(counter) '.jpg'];` the name gets the whole directory. if i'll use the `baseDir` the name doesn't move to **image**

Comment: `newName2 = [baseName num2str(counter) '.jpg'];
set(handles.name,'String',newName2);` got it :) thank you sir